# Programmatically authenticating and accessing service inside AWS EKS cluster from outside when ALB is used

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-eks, amazon-elb, aws-application-load-balancer

We build a Kubernetes application that is deployed by our users, our users connect to the deployed API server using a client and then use that client to submit jobs.

This question is about programmatically connecting to an application running inside Kubernetes cluster from outside of the cluster.

We have this working with local Kubernetes deployments and Google Kubernetes Engine (using IAP).

However some of our users on Amazon cloud cannot connect to the application.

I do not have much experience with AWS. I'm used to token-based auth and OAuth-like auth methods where authentication happens outside of a library: the user is redirected to some page where they log into a service and the client library only gets a token without ever seeing the password.

One of our users have implemented an auth solution that takes username and password and then uses Selenium to emulate the login process and get a cookie which is then used for sending requests. https://github.com/kubeflow/pipelines/pull/4182

Here is a quote from the PR.

> Currently, kfp client can not be used outside AWS EKS cluster. Application load balancer manages outside traffic and require authentication before traffic coming into mesh. This PR automates ALB authentication and get session cookie to authenticate KFP python client to Kubeflow cluster.
> This unblocks user to submit pipeline/run outside kubeflow cluster and user can integrate with their CI/CD solutions much easier.
> Cognito or OIDC behind ALB both can leverage this solution.

Is there a better way to authenticate with AWS EKS ALB?

I've searched the AWS documentation for programmatic authentication methods, but did not find what I wanted (the docs mostly focused on server-side auth setup). In my last search I found the following [article](https://lobster1234.github.io/2018/05/31/server-to-server-auth-with-amazon-cognito/), but I'm not 100% sure it covers what our AWS users want.